# Where does @react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules' come from?

Tags: react-native, cocoapods

I am trying to run an iOS app using React Native. I was running into this error:

```
Invalid `Podfile` file: cannot load such file
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules
```

This pointed to @react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules. So I went into the node_modules folder and tried to find this particular package. It was not there.
I have cli-platform-android but I **do not have cli-platform-ios** which I need.

In package.json I only have **"@react-native-community/cli": "^7.0.4",**. This does install only the android platform. Where does cli-platform-android come from? In order to resolve my issues do I need to separately install this package (the cli platform iOS) in order to run pod install without issues?

Any help is appreciated!

Edit: In order to get any additional feedback or logs or whatever on why your app is not running. Go to Xcode and try to find the experience.xcworks file. This is hidden and you can not see it with anything else besides Xcode(at least on my end).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just install it

> yarn add -D @react-native-community/cli-platform-ios

> yarn add -D @react-native-community/cli-platform-android

And then run `pod install`

Comment: This indeed did get the pod install to run but there is some compilation/build error. I get BUILD FAILED and an advice to run app from Xcode. But I do not have a experience.xcworks file.

Comment: That is a different issue, you have to figure that out yourself.

Comment: This answer is accepted. For anyone wanting to read more, read my edit at the top. Thanks.